# Logging in Erlang: Why there is no library to send an email when an error happens?

Tags: logging, erlang

In some languages, you can attach an email handler to the logging system, so that when an (interested) error happens, you get an email.

But for Erlang, there is no such application/library/(plugin for lager), (at least I cannot find one), why is that? Erlang has some other way to notice the developer?

Of cause I can always roll my own, and some one on mail list has already done that, but given the fact that this is something everyone needs, why there is no such library already?

Comment: What about https://github.com/blinkov/lager_smtp?

Comment: @P_A your googlefu is better than mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077021/logging-in-erlang-why-there-is-no-library-to-send-an-email-when-an-error-happen#comment53971026_33077021) comment, such a library exists for `lager`:

https://github.com/blinkov/lager_smtp